# Protect a range from unhiding but not editing (Google Apps script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hide, rows

Is it possible to prevent people from manually unhiding hidden rows in a spreadsheet?

The person has edit access to the sheet.

How to prevent that with code?

This code below doesn't work (I test it as another user and was able to unhide rows):

```
 //initially hidden range (from chapter 2 down)
var hiddenRange = ss.getRangeByName("CourseProgressHiddenRange")

//get email of a person logged in sheet
var sessionEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() 

//student email from sheet
var studentEmail = ss.getRangeByName("CourseProgressStudentEmail").getValue()

//if student logged in
if (sessionEmail === studentEmail) {

  //protect rows from that email account
  var protection = hiddenRange.protect().setDescription('Hidden rows');
}
```

Comment: I would like to confirm whether my understanding for your goal is correct. Can I do this? You want to make users show the values of the hidden rows without giving the permissions for editing. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: no, they will be able to edit. I open rows for them one by one. I just want to prevent their opening manually all rows at the same time and see what's next. I want to block manual unhiding if that's possible.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor understanding. I could understand that you want to unhide rows using a script without making users unhide rows by themselves. I have 2 questions. 1. In order to make users unhide rows, the rows are required to be protected from the users. Is this matched to your goal? 2. About `The code is unhiding rows for them one by one showing pieces of information.`, how do you want to run the script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function test(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("1:6");
  ss.unhideRow(range);

  var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE);
  protections[0].remove();
}
```

This code will `unhide` ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#unhiderowrow)) the rows of the specified range. After unhiding them it gets all protections in the sheet with `getProtections()` ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getprotectionstype)) and it `removes` the necessary ones ([Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#remove)).

I don't know how your sheet is organized, but using this approach you can unhide the rows you want at the right time, while they are protected, the users cannot expand them. The most important part is that you loop to through the protections in the right way, maybe a method that looks for a particular one, or have the protections named.

Comment: thank you. So before that I need to set protection while rows are hidden and a user will not be able to unhide rows manually because of the protection? Can you please add  that piece of code too?

Comment: That is correct, if the protection is in place only the file's owner can unhide them (it counts as an edit). You can set the protection before or after hiding them, it won't affect anything. Also, what code do you mean, to hide the rows or to protect them? didn't you already do the protection?

Comment: No I have only the code to unhide rows etc. I tried range.protect() thing then logged in under restricted user account but was able to manually unhide the rows. How exactly to use that piece of code to handle that?

Comment: which rows are you hiding and which are you protecting? I tested it and a different user was unable to unhide them manually. For reference, I had rows `2:5` hidden and rows `1:6` protected, so maybe that is what is happening to you.

Comment: I see here you remove protections, that is probably to be able to edit after unhiding. I have difficulties with setting the protection. I used range.protect() and logged in from another account (not listed in editors but I set Anyone with a link can edit) and I could unhide the rows.

Comment: I want person to have editing access to the sheet but to not be able to unhide rows manually.

Comment: The permissions for the protected ranges can be different from the sheet. Meaning, If I shared a file with you and you had edit permissions, but then I protected a particular range, I could set that range so that you cannot edit it, even though you can still edit the rest of the document. In my answer, removing the protect from the particular range is what allows the user to be able to unhide the rows, they can still edit the sheet, they just can't edit the hidden rows (until the script runs)

Comment: @kiki Hi, just wanted to check if the problem was solved?

Comment: no cannot protect rows, still able to unhide. Please check the updated post. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that `hiddenRange` envelops all the rows that need to be hidden? if the protection is not set for any one of them then the user will be able to unhide them